# Breaking for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is what i have done

```
var sampleArr = ['Apple','Mango','Orange','Lemon']

for (var i=0; i < sampleArr.length; i++){
      if (sampleArr[i] === 'Mango'){
         // found Mango no need to go further 
         i = sampleArr.length;
      }
}
```

I have a similar code written in my program where i am using this technique to exit the for loop when a certain condition is met. It works but is it good practice and is there a better alternative present ? I have seen a similar question where there is use of keyword 'break' is it more appropriate to use break ?

Comment: As mentioned, use break. It would be wise to store sampleArr.length in case of large arrays instead of getting it everytime

Comment: Will update my program to use break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) keyword. So your code would look like this:

```
var sampleArr = ['Apple','Mango','Orange','Lemon']

for (var i=0; i < sampleArr.length; i++){
    if (sampleArr[i] === 'Mango'){
        // found Mango no need to go further 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP should be using `Array.prototype.indexOf`

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of `Array.prototype.indexOf`. It will return the index of a matching element or `-1` if the element does not exist in the array.

```js
var sampleArr = ['Apple','Mango','Orange','Lemon'];
var i = sampleArr.indexOf('Mango');
console.log(i); //=> 1

// Here's a key that doesn't exists
var j = sampleArr.indexOf('Chocolate');
console.log(j); //=> -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using this technique instead of `break` standard key word to do the same job. [Read here more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) . It will be more simpler code than this, and also by looking at the code any developer can see it break on your condition. Instead of checking what happens after setting `i = sampleArr.length;`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you should strive to use existing language constructs. In this case, the `break` keyword should fit the bill perfectly:

```
for (var i=0; i < sampleArr.length; i++){
      if (sampleArr[i] === 'Mango'){
         // found Mango no need to go further 
         break; // Here!
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have situation where you need to use the last value of index or last value, your code will not work.

#### Your Code

```js
var sampleArr = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Lemon']

for (var i = 0; i < sampleArr.length; i++) {
  if (sampleArr[i] === 'Mango') {
    // found Mango no need to go further 
    i = sampleArr.length;
  }
}

console.log(sampleArr[i])
```

#### break statement

```js
var sampleArr = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Lemon']

for (var i = 0; i < sampleArr.length; i++) {
  if (sampleArr[i] === 'Mango') {
    // found Mango no need to go further 
    break;
  }
}
console.log(sampleArr[i])
```

**Note:** Its better to use `break`. Updating value of i sounds more like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can include multiple expressions it in the condition:

```
for (var i=0; i < sampleArr.length && sampleArr[i] != 'Mango'; i++)
```

but *break* is probably clearer.